# How to extend Client and Socket objects in Socket.io@4.2.0 and typescript@4.4.3

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

How can I extend *Client* and *Socket* objects in socket.io@4.2.0 to add custom fields?

Previously, in socket.io@2.x.x I could do something like below:

```
export interface CustomClient extends Client {
  customField: string;
}

export interface CustomSocket extends Socket {
  client: CustomClient;
}
```

I want to achieve the same thing with socket.io@4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Do not extend it anymore. Use the data field which has the type of any and add all the necessary data there.

Comment: The client socket has no data field. Can you expand on your answer?